# Question about normal distribution statistics

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am doing a project about descision analysis, but I don't understand one crucial step in my book. F(x) is the standard normal cumulative distribution function, and we have:
$$F(x) = 0.744$$
From this, it follows that
$$x = 0.6557$$
Why is this? And where can I find $x$ when
$$F(x) = 0.8$$?

Comment: Does your book have any tables at the end ?

Comment: No, we are not at home, or in a mathematics environment. Didn't expect to get in touch with propability matters, so we don't have a book with us.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally done by looking at the tables. Though it possible without them, it would be difficult and time consuming. So everyone follows [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table).

If the exact value is not found, to get the approximate value you need to interpolate/extrapolate the values around the required value.

So for $F(x)=0.8$, $x$ lies between $0.84$ and $0.85$. Assuming linear interpolation you can get the most approximate value for $F(x)=0.8$